# Does BareOs support includes in configuration files?

Tags: bacula, bareos

I know when I do an Apache2 configuration it supports the inclusion of other files.  Does BareOS support this functionality?

Comment: This document appears to have yielded a result for bacula: http://www.bacula.org/5.2.x-manuals/en/main/main.pdf 

if you search for `Including other Configuration Files`